# Errors with relationships between Entities with Code First EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

I am busy building a ASP.NET webapplication for a project at my university. It looked easy and simple to me how to configure the relations between entities with Code First Entity Framework (.NET). As soon as I want to 'add-migration -name', the first errors occur. There is something I understood wrong with this concept.

Like the following:

In my case I have 6 entities which also have relations with eachother.

My Session entity has the following relations with other classes:

```
[Table("Session")]
public class Session
{
    [Key()]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //non-relevant properties
    [ForeignKey("StudentsAttention")]
    public Guid StudentsAttentionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Course")]
    public Guid CourseId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Klas")]
    public Guid KlasId { get; set; }
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Klas Klas { get; set; }
    public virtual StudentsAttention StudentsAttention { get; set; }
}
```

Klas entity:

```
[Table("Klas")]
public class Klas
{
    [Key()]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //not relevant
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Course entity:

```
[Table("Course")]
public class Course
{
    [Key()]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //not relevant
    [ForeignKey("Session")]
    public Guid SessionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
}
```

Teacher entity:

```
[Table("Teacher")]
public class Teacher
{
    [Key()]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //not relevant
    [ForeignKey("Session")]
    public Guid SessionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
}
```

Student entity:

```
[Table("Student")]
public class Student
{
    [Key()]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //not relevant
    [ForeignKey("Klas")]
    public Guid KlasId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Klas Klas { get; set; }
}
```

It gives me a lot of errors, but I am sure that most of you will see the problems instantly. So my question is, how do I fix the entity relations?

If two entities have a one-to-many relation, I do the next thing:

```
public class EntityA
{
   public virtual ICollection<EntityB> EntityBs { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
   [ForeignKey("EntityA")]
   public Guid EntityAId { get; set; }
   public virtual EntityA EntityA { get; set; }
}
```

One-to-one relation:

```
public class EntityA
{
   [ForeignKey("B")]
   public Guid EntityBId { get; set; }
   public virtual EntityB B { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
   [ForeignKey("A")]
   public Guid EntityA { get; set; }
   public virtual EntityA A { get; set; }
}
```

I am sure configuring my relations like this will give me multiple errors. How do I configure my relations in the right way. I know this has probably been asked 100 times, but that help hasn't fixed my problems.

Comment: Can you specify what the EF & ASP.NET version is that you are using

Comment: @TomDroste EF version: 6.1.3   ASP.NET version 4.5.2